# Concat function returns 0 from one of my columns

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I was trying to insert a concatenate my four columns, however after doing so, one column wasn't being returned right, instead of the respective value of my serial_id, it only gives 0.

Here is the code i was trying to enter and I have provided pictures.

```
INSERT INTO burseid (tag_id,mm,yyyy,combo)
VALUES ('CV',MONTH(NOW()),YEAR(NOW()),CONCAT(tag_id,'-',serial_id,'-',mm,'-',yyyy);
```

[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ncuG.png)

I'm looking to return the values as CV-01-mm-yyyy, but it keeps returning the serial_id as 0 in any of the rows, unless i manually change it.

Here's the sample data [sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auAmB.png)

Comment: you nedd to concat 'CV',MONTH(NOW()),YEAR(NOW())

Comment: tag_id value is either CV or DB. serial_id value is auto increment. mm and yyyy value is set to current date.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.  Are you looking to _update_ your existing table with a computed column?  Are you looking to _insert_ new records?  Something else?

Comment: how am i going to insert serial_id in between tag_id and mm if i were to concatenate them beforehand?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i'm looking to just insert new records.

Comment: What version of mysql are you on? And do you really need a column combo or would a compound key do? Also have you heard of generated columns?

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldn't even run as far as I know, and it looks like you should be doing an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO burseid (tag_id, mm, yyyy, combo)
SELECT 'CV', MONTH(NOW()), YEAR(NOW()), CONCAT(tag_id,'-',serial_id,'-',mm,'-',yyyy)
FROM other_table;
```

Comment: doesn't work for me, because i use the same table, however when I created another table, this solution of yours worked.

combo should return on my table as

CV-01-11-2018

but it returned as

CV-0-11-2018

Comment: Edit your question and explain it using sample data.

Comment: Combo is an indexed column which makes me suspect op may actually need a compound key or a generated column. And it should be populated (if that's a requirement) at insert - not from another table.